# Vue attribute selector with or without modifiers

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[Vue directives support hooks](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Directive-Hook-Arguments) like

```
[v-directive:argument.modifier="value"]
```

Does Vue expose a way to query for elements that match just `[v-directive]` with or without arguments and/or modifiers? Or `[v-directive:argument]` with or without modifiers?

Comment: You can examine the `$vnode.data.directives` property of any component to find directives that are on that component. I don't know of any provided way to search the entire component tree.

Comment: @BertEvans My use case is to find other elements using the same directive and/or directive argument from within my directive definition without saving/unsaving references on bind/unbind

Comment: What do you need to do with them? Using the vnode passed to the directive hooks, you could get to $root and then recursively examine all child vnodes for matching directives, but not knowing what you want to do with them I'm not sure if that would help.